# Python Pandas read_sql_query “'NoneType' object is not iterable” error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyodbc

I am trying to execute a sql and save a result into Panda Dataframe. here is my code.

```
        dbserver = 'validserver'
        filename = 'myquery.sql'
        database  ='validdb'       
        conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=' + dbserver + 
            ';Database=' + database + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        fd = open(filename, 'r')
        resultingData = pd.read_sql_query(fd.read(),conn)
        fd.close()
        conn.close()
```

line `pd.read_sql_query(fd.read(),conn)` continues to give me error 
'NoneType' object is not iterable” error

I can run myquery.sql in a sql server window with results. I do have `SET NOCOUNT ON;`

Any clue what am I missing here and how do I debug this? myquery.sql has few #temp tables and joins. Result has about 75k rows. Thanks all.

**Update:**

I can not post the exact query but this is how query looks like.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT SourceID, PeriodEndDate = MAX(PeriodEndDate)
INTO #SourceDate 
FROM table1
WHERE PERIODENDDATE <= 20171229
GROUP BY SourceID

SELECT RS.*, R.TypeCode INTO #final
FROM table2 RS
INNER JOIN #SourceDate SD ON SD.id = RS.id
INNER JOIN table3 R ON R.id = RS.id

select * from #final
```

Comment: Please show contents of *myquery.sql*. Only single SQL `SELECT` statements should be passed into `read_sql()`.

Comment: @Parfait I have updated my question with query.

Comment: Can you modify the .sql script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I understand, `read_sql_query()` would only return the results from your first statement anyhow.  In which case, it's `SET NOCOUNT ON;` and as you can see, will return `None`, which is why your code failed.  IMO You should be optimizing your SQL statement to return one table instead of multiple in the process (as you only want to read from #final I assume).

If you really want to have multiple sql query in a dataframe, you can use `lists` and `split` as mentioned in this thread:

[Pandas read_sql query with multiple selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646214/pandas-read-sql-query-with-multiple-selects)

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I converted my query to a stored procedure and was able to call it with read_sql_query().

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes tsql warnings like `Warning: Null value is Eliminated by an Aggregate or Other SET Operation` can trigger the same problematic behaviour for `pd.read_sql()`. I found that additionally setting these warnings off helps in this situation. For that just add

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
```

besides your `SET NOCOUNT ON;` statement.

Of course you shouldn't just ignore these waringns. Check if your result is as expected before setting the warnings off.

Answer (score 3):

As @r.ook mentioned, use `SET NOCOUNT ON;` for each statement that returns "NoneType". So, your statement might be:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT SourceID, PeriodEndDate = MAX(PeriodEndDate)
INTO #SourceDate 
FROM table1
WHERE PERIODENDDATE <= 20171229
GROUP BY SourceID

SET NOCOUNT ON; --Added "SET NOCOUNT ON;" here as well.
SELECT RS.*, R.TypeCode INTO #final
FROM table2 RS
INNER JOIN #SourceDate SD ON SD.id = RS.id
INNER JOIN table3 R ON R.id = RS.id

select * from #final
```

You can also check [this link](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/171675) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove the semicolon after "SET NOCOUNT ON" and then run the script.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29989460)