# Multiple SQL statements in pandas.read_sql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

So I have a SQL query with has the following structure:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE a
Select id, time
from t1 ;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE b
Select id, views
from t2 ;

Select a.id, a.time, b.views from a join b on a.id=b.id;
```

Which is saved in a .sql file that I want to read in pd.read_sql()

However, since there are multiple SQL statements it does not seem to work.

Any clues on where to look at?

Thanks

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE a AS SELECT ...` Missing as?

Comment: No, not for mysql

Comment: Duplicate/related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646214/pandas-read-sql-query-with-multiple-selects

Comment: Different problem: my final query is the result of the merge of two temp tables

Answer (score 0):

You need a "SET NOCOUNT ON" at the top of your script. This will avoid returning the empty result set for number of rows inserted by first 2 inserts.